# How do I pass an argument to a Google App Engine servlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I created a servlet that sends email alerts on a specified condition.  the users can set alerts through the gui on the main page, but i want to give them the option of unregistering in each email thats sent.   i want to include something like this in the email:

```
If you'd like to unregister for this alert, please go to http://mysite.com/myUnregisterServlet?id=uniqueID
```

where uniqueID would be the alerts unique key (there can be many different alerts set for 1 email).

how can i accomplish this, or something to this effect?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws IOException, ServletException
{
  final String id = req.getParameter("id");
  ...
}
```